# How to write total counting object on image with yolo v5?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolov5

[result image detection with out text sum counting object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpHoa.jpg)

My expectation on image i can write total counting on image result. Save result image with total counting object detection on image. In video result counting object is work but on image not working. Please give me answers and information about this problem